# Update custom fields with profiles?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile, forms

Actually I would like registered contacts to be able to fill out some **custom fields** in the **easiest way possible**.
I was thinking of a **"form"** type link and here they can enter their contact id (to match the information with the corresponding contact) + additional information from custom fields. I don't want them to have to create an account to fill in the information, so we were thinking about using profiles, but I haven't found a way to do it.

We are using **WordPress** and we already have all the contacts created.

Comment: Have you had a look at Form Builder?

Comment: @Petednz-Fuzion Yes I did, but Form Builder only "Create" but not "Update" using a Contact ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Caldera forms to do or CiviCRM profiles. You can email the link to the contact with the contact id and checksum in the URL. This will auto-populate the details for the contact automatically.

Comment: Caldera Forms is no longer available, is it?

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/community-maintained-fork-caldera-forms